# Firestore Pagination query not returning all results

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I have implemented pagination firestore query to return results 5 at a time.

It first starts by creating a listener and pulling 5 results. On the pull to refresh it pulls 5 more results. On the 2nd pull to refresh it for some reason pulls 10 results. On the 3rd pull to refresh it doesn't pull any results. After looking at the data some data is missing.

**Below is my MessageListener function:**

```
func createMessageListener() {
    reference = db.collection(["chats", channel.id!, "messages"].joined(separator: "/"))

    let first = reference?.order(by: "created", descending: true).limit(to: 5)

    messageListener = first!.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            print("Error listening for channel updates: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No error")")
            return
        }

        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { change in
            self.handleDocumentChange(change)
            self.updateReadStatus()
        }

        guard let lastSnapshot = snapshot.documents.last else {
            // The collection is empty.
            self.hasMoreMessages = false
            return
        }

        self.last = self.reference?.order(by: "created", descending: true).start(afterDocument: lastSnapshot).limit(to: 5)
    }
}
```

**Below is my loadMoreMessages function:**

```
func loadMoreMessages() {

    if hasMoreMessages {
        last!.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
                print("Error listening for channel updates: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No error")")
                self.hasMoreMessages = false
                self.delegate.viewModelDidLoadMoreMessages(hasMoreMessages: self.hasMoreMessages)
                return
            }
            self.moreMessagesLoaded = true
            snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { change in
                self.handleDocumentChange(change)
            }
            self.delegate.viewModelDidLoadMoreMessages(hasMoreMessages: true)

            guard let lastSnapshot = snapshot.documents.last else {
                // The collection is empty.
                self.hasMoreMessages = false
                return
            }

            self.last = self.reference?.start(afterDocument: lastSnapshot)
        }
    } else {
        self.delegate.viewModelDidLoadMoreMessages(hasMoreMessages: self.hasMoreMessages)
    }
}
```

Not too sure what is going on. If in the create listener function i change the first limit to 35 for example. It will pull all the data.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I'm not sure I follow everything, as there's quite a bit of different pieces to your code. But as far as I can see, the `snapshot.documentChanges.forEach` in your second snippet should only contain (at most) 5 documents. If you put a simple `print` statement in there, does it fire more than 5 times?

Comment: Yes it fires more than 5 times. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Can you edit your question to how the updated code, and the print output? Since this problem happens on your system, you'll need to help us debug it. So don't just print a random value, but for example print the ID of the documents returns, so that we can see how the different queries are returning different, or the same, documents.